# Java records Generics : non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

```
 public record Result<T>() {
    private static ResultState state;
    private static Exception exception;
    private static T value;

    public Result(T value) {
        state = ResultState.Success;
        value = value;
        exception = null;
    }

    public Result(Exception e) {
        state = ResultState.Faulted;
        exception = e;
        value = null;
    }

    public static Supplier<Boolean> isFaulted = () -> state == ResultState.Faulted;

    public static Supplier<Boolean> isSuccess = () -> state == ResultState.Success;

    public void match(Consumer<T> succ, Consumer<Exception> fail) {
        if (isFaulted.get())
            fail.accept(exception);
        else
            succ.accept(value);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
    private static T value;
               ^
```

Comment: Why did you make them static?

Comment: Because it is a record and we can only declare a static fields

Comment: You can declare them in the constructor brackets,  just after the record name. But I don't think `Result` should be a record...

Comment: Why did you make it a record? (without components))

Comment: And what exactly is your question? That's just a code dump

Answer (score 2):

Since `T` is a generic type that can differ from one instance to another, you cannot use it for a static field. It doesn't have to do with records, it's just how java works. For instance, if you write this class, you'll get the same complication error:

```java
class MyClass<T> {
    public static T staticField; // ... cannot be referenced from a static context
}
```

As a result, if you replace the generic type `T` with `Object`, your code example will work:

```
static record Result<T>() {
    private static ResultState state;
    private static Exception exception;
    private static Object value;
   
    // ...
}
```

However, this looks wrong because each computation will override the previous (static) result. In my opinion, the correct way would be declare the *state, value* and *exception* fields inside the record itself, like this:

```java
static record Result<T>(
    ResultState state,
    T value,
    Exception exception
) {

    public Result(T value) {
        this(ResultState.Success, value, null);
    }

    public Result(Exception e) {
        this(ResultState.Success, null, e);
    }

    public void match(Consumer<T> succ, Consumer<Exception> fail) {
        if (state == ResultState.Faulted)
            fail.accept(exception);
        else
            succ.accept(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good. Maybe just `if (state == ResultState.Faulted)` instead and delete `isFaulted()` and `isSuccess()` methods.